# How can I combine multiple case statements in Bash?

Tags: bash, case

Apologies in advance if this is basic knowledge, I began my foray into Bash a couple of hours ago.

I have two case statements that I would like to combine, if that is possible. Could someone help me please? I can't seem to figure it out.

If it is March 5th for example I would want the result to be さんがついつか.

I have

```
case $(LC_ALL=C date +%m) in

(01) echo いちがつ;;
(02) echo にがつ;;
(03) echo さんがつ;;
(04) echo しがつ;;
(05) echo ごがつ;;

esac
```

and

```
$(LC_ALL=C date +%d) in
(01) echo ついたちい;;
(02) echo ふつか;;
(03) echo みっか;;
(04) echo よっか;;
(05) echo いつか;;

esac
```

For context I'm studying Japanese, and want to use this script in [Textbar](http://richsomerfield.com/apps/textbar/) to help me learn the days and months in hiragana.

Comment: Set a variable in each case statement. Then echo the two variables concatenated.

Comment: Or have the first case statement print the month name with no newline at the end.

Comment: @Barmar thank you, would you be able to provide a quick example? This is all new to me.

Comment: If assigning variables is new to you, you need to read a scripting tutorial. SO is not a tutoring service, you're expected to know the basics.

Comment: @Barmar OK, that's completely fair. Sorry. Thanks for the below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign a variable instead of echoing the value immediately. Then echo the two variables together after both `case` statements.

```
case $(LC_ALL=C date +%m) in

    (01) month='いちがつ' ;;
    (02) month='にがつ' ;;
    (03) month='さんがつ' ;;
    (04) month='しがつ' ;;
    (05) month='ごがつ' ;;
esac
case $(LC_ALL=C date +%d) in
    (01) date='ついたちい' ;;
    (02) date='ふつか' ;;
    (03) date='みっか' ;;
    (04) date='よっか' ;;
    (05) date='いつか' ;;
esac

echo "$month $date"
```